# How make PayPal checkout redirect to Kivy Python App?

Tags: python, paypal, kivy

I currently have a Python Kivy app that has a PayPal option for checkout that opens the PayPal checkout page with `webbrowser`. I was wondering if there's a way that the PayPal checkout page can bring me back to my Python Kivy App after clicking Continue? Or atleast send some sort of information to my Python script that the customer has clicked continue so they can proceed to confirm and place the order?

The PayPal checkout screen I'm mentioning is this one:[image]

Here's my .py file in case it may be useful

```
class CheckoutScreen(Screen):
    def PayPal(self):
        # Create Access Token
        client_id = "ID"
        client_secret = "SECRET"

        # Creating an environement
        environment = SandboxEnvironment(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
        client = PayPalHttpClient(environment)

        request = OrdersCreateRequest()
        request.prefer("return=representation")

        request.request_body(
            {
                "intent": "CAPTURE",
                "purchase_units": [
                    {
                        "amount": {
                            "currency_code": "CAD",
                            "value": str(App.get_running_app().cart)
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })

        try:
            response = client.execute(request)
            print("Order With Complete Payload:")
            print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
            print("Status:", response.result.status)
            print("Order ID:", response.result.id)
            print("Intent:", response.result.intent)
            print("Links:")
            for link in response.result.links:
                print('\t{}: {}\tCall Type: {}'.format(link.rel, link.href, link.method))
                print("Total Amount: {} {}".format(response.result.purchase_units[0].amount.currency_code,
                                                   response.result.purchase_units[0].amount.value))
                order = response.result
                print(order)
        except IOError as ioe:
            print(ioe)
            if isinstance(ioe, HttpError):
                # Something went wrong server side
                print(ioe.status_code)
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=" + response.result.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your request_body, specify an application_context with a `return_url` that has a value which is a deeplink back to your app.

API Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2#orders-create-request-body

That link will have a parameter added to it with the orderID. Although it is an app, use this to validate what the return is for and show an order review page to then trigger the capture on final approval.

If you want to do the capture immediately (no review page), you should change the verbiage of the button on PayPal from 'Continue' to "Pay Now" so the user is aware there's no more review step. This is done with the `user_action` variable in the application_context.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will look into it

Comment: One more thing, is there some sort of documentation for deeplinking? I've never worked with it before.